# Вещдоки Латинского Языка.

Tags: лингвистика

Вопрос славистам и языковедам (прошу, по возможности, ответить простым языком):

Перечислите, пожалуйста, признаки (свидетельства), которые дают право каждому из нас утверждать, что латинский язык (классическая латынь) действительно существовал, скажем, уже к Рождеству Христову (около 1 года н.э.).

Заранее спасибо за ваш труд и желание помочь!

Comment: Дают право каждому из нас утверждать...что латынь действительно существовала... уже к рождеству? Нет это ребус какой-то. А кто вам не дает право-то чего-то утверждать, я не пойму?

Comment: Ну, хотя бы к Рождеству.
Не говорю уже о глубокой античности.

Право утверждать?
А то, что на идее древности латинской культуры построено все историческое здание Европы, это не аргумент?

Comment: > Вещдоки Латинского Языка. 
> Вопрос славистам и языковедам (...)

:-) А слависты тут причём? Не понимаю. Латынь - не славянский язык.

Да и вообще, это форум **"Русский язык"**. Мне кажется, вопрос не совсем по теме форума.

Comment: Николай, расскажу - почему желательно вмешательство славистов.
Нами обнаружены исконно русские (слав.) слова, которые в этимологиях приписываются почему-то грекам, латинянам, индусам и тому подобным древним культурам.

Естественно возникает вопрос - каким образом эти слова (корни) "попали", например, в латинский, если их зарождение произошло гораздо позже, да еще и на просторах Средне-Русской равнины?

Надежда на то, что знатоки-слависты не пропустят это обращение и дадут квалифицированную оценку.

Отсюда и наш вопрос, и сомнение, что латинский язык мог появиться раньше русского (др.-русс.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бог ты мой... Слависты и языковеды. )))))))))))))))))))))

**Цицерон**. Это просто навскидку. Читайте, завидуйте. )) Или это подделка?

Comment: Да, Цицерон подделка.
Постарайтесь не ссылаться на историографию.
Самих же письменных античных источников, уверен, вы это знаете, не сохранилось.

Есть ли свидетельства независимые от исторических изысканий? Т.е. в составе самой классической латыни?

PS. Слависты здесь тоже нужны.
Если надо - объясню почему.

Comment: Ну, тогда предоставляю возможность вам самому объявить всё-всё-всё, что дошло до нас на латыни, подделкой.

А кто так искусно подделал-то, не скажете? Ведь создать такой язык, как латынь — не шутка. Например, "специалистам" типа Феди такое не под силу... Так кто же?

Comment: Нет, стало быть, никаких свидетельств древности латинского языка?
Спасибо!

Comment: Аффтара латыни в студию.

Comment: Вот объясните, каким образом в латинском появилось слово ГЕРОЙ, т.е. современное HEROS? 

Если идти по ранжиру, латиняне могли выловить его из греческого ΗΡΩΑΣ (ИРОАС). Так?

 А у латинян, вероятно, переняли и получили своего героя англичане -  HERO = герой, и т.д., где одними из последних оказывается, естественно, русское ГЕРОЙ. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: Только вот что пишет Фасмер:
вероятно, из франц. héros "герой", как и герои́ня – из франц. héroïne (-иня по аналогии боги́ня и т. д.). Форма герои́ческий соответствует франц. héroïque и нем. heroisch. В XVIII в. вместо них – иро́й, ирои́ческий под влиянием ср.-греч. и нов.-греч. произношения слова ἥΟΩΣ.


Заметили особенность?
Не часто встретишь свидетельства в русских справочниках, пусть и завуалированного, что французское или английское средневековое пополнило греческий словарь! Или ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не задумывались почему и как расставляются приоритеты старшинства культур? Но почему, скажите, не исходить от обратного, и не искать из русск. ГЕРОЙ происхождения латинского HEROS ?

Comment: Как же вы меня утомили... Последний раз отвечаю. Я что, нанимался вас учить? 

Слово "герой" русский язык заимствовал (как предполагает Фасмер) именно из *французского*, а не из латыни и не из греческого. Вот и всё. Откуда это слово заимствовал *французский язык* — это не тема словаря Фасмера. Понятно, да?

Не демонстрируйте же свое невежество, не выставляйте его напоказ.

Answer (score 2):

Из совсем железобетонных доказательств - это надписи на домах Помпеи (уничтожена в 79 г. н. э.). В раскопках этого города, помимо надписей, сохранилось множество органики для углеродного анализа и деревьев - для дендрохронологического.

Comment: 79 год от Р.Х - неверная дата гибели Помпей.
Материалов на эту тему уже предостаточно.
Всё свидетельствует об их более поздней гибели (16 или 17 век).

Стало быть, Ваши железобетонные доказательства (надписи на домах Помпеи) могут свидетельствовать совсем о другом.

А именно - латинская письменность - это позднее образование.

Comment: Niemand, когда же я Вас успел так утомить?

Приведите, пожалуйста, языковедческие свидетельства древности латинского языка.

Comment: @Федя, с дендрохронологией не поспоришь, а дерева в раскопках предостаточно.

Comment: Хорошо, не поспоришь.
Но как Вы объясните обнаруженные сюжеты Рафаэля в разрушенных в 1 веке до Н.э. Помпеях и Геркулануме?

Comment: @Федя, 

1. Помпеи и Геркуланум, как я уже упомянул в ответе разрушены в I веке **нашей эры**.

2. Сюжеты обнаружены не Рафаэля, а древнеримских мифов. Эти сюжеты в своих картинах использовали и художники эпохи Возрождения, в том числе и Рафаэль.

3. Учитывая неоспоримость дендрохронологии, все эти рассуждения о сюжетах для датировки не важны.

Comment: Очень хорошо!
Важно, что в сгоревших в 1 веке Помпеях сохранились до наших дней стволы, позволившие датировать латинские надписи!

Не знаю, где Вы знакомились с этими свидетельствами.
Важно, что Вы уверены в этом вопросе, и хорошо знаете предмет разговора.

Comment: Как и ожидалось, дендрохронология Помпей оказалась фальсификатом:

В публикации [Kuniholm, 2002] как бы само собой подразумевается, что дендрошкала по Помпеям и Геркулануму характеризует эти античные города. Однако это не так. Ее основу составили дендрохронологические данные, полученные по строительным балкам Склада плотника в Геркулануме. Однако они имеют следы использования по назначению. То есть, эти балки выполняли свои инженерные функции в зданиях, которые по каким-то причинам были разрушены. Где находились эти здания? Может быть, они были в Геркулануме, может быть в Неаполе, может быть.

Answer (score -2):

Для **Марк Из**

Как и ожидалось, дендрохронология Помпей оказалась фальсификатом:

В публикации [Kuniholm, 2002] как бы само собой подразумевается, что дендрошкала по Помпеям и Геркулануму характеризует эти античные города. Однако это не так. Ее основу составили дендрохронологические данные, полученные по строительным балкам Склада плотника в Геркулануме. Однако они имеют следы использования по назначению. То есть, эти балки выполняли свои инженерные функции в зданиях, которые по каким-то причинам были разрушены. Где находились эти здания? Может быть, они были в Геркулануме, может быть в Неаполе, может быть..

Кто это знает?
Для того, чтобы понять смысл публикации [Kuniholm, 2002] нужно знать, что ее автор является одним из руководителей Эгейского дендрохронологического проекта. Его состояние рассмотрено в публикации [Тюрин, 2007, Эгейский проект]. Более 30 лет назад Эгейский проект задумывался как грандиозное научное мероприятие, главной целью которого являлось создание инструмента независимого дендрохронологического датирования артефактов древних цивилизаций Восточно-Средиземноморского региона.

Но сегодня Эгейский проект - блеф. В этом и заключается реальный смысл выполняемых в его рамках работ в течение, по крайней мере, последнего десятилетия. Построение и абсолютное датирование плавающей дендрошкалы Помпей и Геркуланума – одна из составляющих этого блефа. Об этом свидетельствует то, что эти работы выполнены в годах (абсолютное датирование дендрошкалы выполнено в 1997 году), а их результаты опубликованы в 2002 году. Судя по библиографии Эгейского дендрохронологического проекта [Bibliography], никаких других публикаций по этому вопросу не имеется. То есть, реальный смысл публикации [Kuniholm, 2002], презентующий результаты 5-летней давности, заключается в демонстрации того, что Эгейский дендрохронологический проект в 2002 году, как бы, успешно развивается. Это мы и называем блефом.

Comment: Есть хорошая работа по Помпеям: http://new.chronologia.org/volume7/turin_dendrochron_pompei.php под названием Дендрохронология Помпей и Геркуланума, А.М. Тюрин.

О разрушенных в 17 веке Помпеях можно почитать и здесь: http://newlit.ru/~izbushkin/5132.html

Comment: @Федя, а Вы в курсе, что в приведённом вами ответе пытается опровергнуть дендрохронологическую шкалу Помпей только одна фраза?

>Где находились эти здания?

Отвечаю на неё - Неважно, важно где выросли деревья и когда их спилили, а на эти вопросы современная дендрохронология отвечает достаточно точно.

Весь остальной ваш пассаж не имеет никакого отношения к точности датировки. Каким бы плохим или хорошим  человеком не был Пифагор, но его теорема верна.

Comment: А почему ответ, находящийся над этими комментариями, теперь подписан **"Cообщество ХэшКод"**? Что это значит?

Comment: Как хотите, не желаете изучать - Ваше дело.
Желаете упорствовать - упорствуйте.
Всему свое время.

Comment: >А почему ответ, находящийся над этими комментариями, теперь подписан      
  
Есть тут такое понятие как "общий вопрос". Ну вроде от имени всего сообщества - как результат коллективного разума. Он и поисковиками быстрее находится (ну так по замыслу) и здесь вроде как большая весомость. 

Вопрос не в том, что это значит, а в том, почему я не могу вернуть этот поток сознания автору?

Comment: Niemandу

Фасмер не уверен в ГЕРОЕ, как выходце "именно из французского", его вариант - вероятностный. Кроме того, далее он указывает на параллели: ...под влиянием ср.-греч. и нов.-греч. произношения слова ἥοως.

     Не знаю, отчего вы так озлоблены и ругливы? Вас буквально два-три человека, а столько напора и апломба!
Неужели так трудно видеть простые вещи?

     Те же Помпеи. Сколько ныне расследовано, столько передоказано, так нет же, надо непременно продолжать упорствовать в заблуждениях историков 18 века! Ребята, протрите глаза, в 21 веке пора бы уж и опрокинуть заблуждения предков!